# Show trending post of a category

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to show the trending post of a category.  I only want to display 1 post.  I define trending as trending in the moment.

For example:

Post A is 100 days old, had 100K views total, around 1K views a day.

Post B is 10 days old, had 10K views, 8K of them in last day.

A is long time popular, but B is trending at this moment (even though before that it had lower daily and all time traffic levels than A).

```
<?php

$today = getdate();
$args = array(
          'meta_key'     => 'post_views',
          'meta_value'   => '1000',
          'meta_compare' => '>=',
          'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
          'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'cat' => 14,
        'numberposts' => 1,
          'paged' => $paged,
          'date_query' => array(
                array(
                        'year'  => $today['year'],
                        'month' => $today['mon'],
                         'day'   => $today['mday'],
    ),
),
);
$trenquery = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $trenquery->have_posts() ) {

get_the_title();

    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

functions.php

```html
// Popular Posts
function wpb_set_post_views($postID) { 
$count_key = 'wpb_post_views_count'; 
$count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true); 
if($count==''){ 
$count = 0; 
delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key); 
add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, 0); 
}else{ 
$count++; 
update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count); 
} 
} 
//To keep the count accurate, lets get rid of prefetching 
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);

function wpb_track_post_views ($post_id) { 
if ( !is_single() ) return; 
if ( empty ( $post_id) ) { 
global $post; 
$post_id = $post->ID; 
} 
wpb_set_post_views($post_id); 
} 
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpb_track_post_views');
```

Answer (score 0):

Query the posts for most viewed post for today, try this.

```
$today = getdate();
$args = array(
    'meta_key'          => 'post_views_count',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'date_query'        => array(
        array(
            'year'  => $today['year'],
            'month' => $today['mon'],
            'day'   => $today['mday']
        )
    )
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);

if($my_query->have_posts()) : while($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

        get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'post_views_count', true);

    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

Comment: your post have post view count functionality, check in your database like whole search wit a keyword " post_views_count ", If this meta have your wp_postmeta table then only it will work or else you need to enable post view functionality in your website.

Comment: I've added this function to my question.  Even with this function it still will not work.

Comment: Did you check in DB, post view count stored in your DB ?